# Neo4J - How to exclude self referenced nodes in allShortestPaths?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to find all shortest paths given a particular length. Below is the query I am using:

```
match (n:Person{email:'sam@gmail.com'}),
(k:Person{email:'joseph@gmail.com'}),
paths=allShortestPaths((n)-[r:CONNECTED_TO*..2]->(k))
where length(paths)=2
with collect(paths) as path
unwind path as p
return nodes(p) as nodes,rels(p) as relations
```

Issue is I have self referenced nodes in the database of the form

```
(n:Person{email:'sam@gmail.com'})-[:CONNECTED_TO]->
(n:Person{email:'sam@gmail.com'})
```

I want to exclude these paths in my shortest path query. Can anyone guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a predicate in your WHERE clause after your shortest path call to exclude these:

```
match (n:Person{email:'sam@gmail.com'}),
(k:Person{email:'joseph@gmail.com'}),
path=allShortestPaths((n)-[:CONNECTED_TO*..2]->(k))
where length(path) = 2 and none(rel in relationships(path) where startNode(rel) = endNode(rel))
return nodes(path) as nodes, relationships(path) as relations
```